# Возможно ли реализовать классы с наследованием так, чтобы в наследнике находился свой метод, который и так был до этого расписан в базовом классе?

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Чтобы было более понятно, привожу свой пример:
**Базовый класс:**

```
internal class State : IFunctional 
{

   public void Add(string name, string desc)
   {
      ...
   }

}
```

**Наследник:**

```
internal class Country : State, IFunctional
{

   public new void Add(string t_name, string t_desc)
   {
      ...
   }

}
```

Таким образом, я думал, что, работая с объектом типа **Country**, я смогу использовать обе реализации метода **Add**, скажем, например, в случае как с интерфейсами, то есть с помощью явной реализации. Однако данный способ оказался нереализуем, а других путей я не нашел, поэтому пришлось менять название в одном из классов, чтобы они не совпадали и одна реализация не перекрывала другую (**Add** -> **AddState**). Можно ли каким-то способом добиться того результата, который мне нужен, или это вообще не представляется возможным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> данный способ оказался нереализуем

После этих слов желательно показать "реализацию".

---

```
Country c = new Country();
c.Add("a", "b"); // from Country
((State)c).Add("a", "b"); // from State
```

---

```
State c = new Country();
c.Add("a", "b"); // from State
((Country)c).Add("a", "b"); // from Country
```